# This browser is not supported by Shopify While Authenticating Using Web Browser Control In Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

When we are using a WebBrowser control in windows forms application for shopify authentication we are getting the following error:

> "This browser is not supported by Shopify    We recommend using Google Chrome or upgrading your current browser's software.   You can    but the experience may be severely degraded or dysfunctional. You can also go back to Shopify Classic."

Can you please let us know, what needs to be done to overcome this situation for authenticating?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not describe at all what you are trying to do and what problem you are trying to solve in doing so, so my only suggestion is:

Don't use a Web Browser control, but use an HTTP client like HttpClient or HttpWebRequest and access their [API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth).

There's even have a [.NET library](https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/shopify.net) for that.